# Visual Studio Team Services 'User's Manual'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

As the leader of a small team, I need to figure out how to use and administer the Visual Studio Team Services / Team Foundation Server 2013 ecosystem.  I am finding the learning curve to be very steep.  Can anyone point me to how-to and tutorial resources along the lines of 'VS Team Services / TFS 2013 for Dummies'?  At this point, I really just want to be able to use VS Team Services for source control.  I am not yet interested on the full ALM.

Comment: Per the close reasons, **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."**

Answer (score 1):

It's a great question John.  My suggestion would be to start in the Getting Started content for Visual Studio Team Services:  https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/overview

Additionally, there are books available for Team Foundation Server 2013 & Visual Studio Team Services.  I can selfishly recommend [Professional Team Foundation Server 2013](http://aka.ms/TFS2013Book) from Wrox as one of those printed resources.

[image: Professional Team Foundation Server Book Cover]

Comment: Thanks. I will check out the book.